# Excel: Dynamically condensing worksheets from multiple files into one workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have about ten files that contain identically formatted/structured data (the first four rows are information, fifth is the header, and every row after that is the data itself; also, the first column is blank for margin purposes). I'd like to dynamically merge them all into one worksheet. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You weren't very specific, but you can try this. It will combine all files within a folder into one. You will have to adapt it to the data you have (where row headers are, etc).

```
Sub MergeFiles()
'Description: Combines all files in a folder to a master file.
    Dim path As String
    Dim ThisWB As String
    Dim lngFilecounter As Long
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Wkb As Workbook
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim Dest As Range
    Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

    RowofCopySheet = 3 ' Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from

    ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    path = GetFolder("")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Add
    ChDir path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        (path & "combinedfilesforfolder.xlsm"), FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
            Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), _
                Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count))
            Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
            CopyRng.Copy Dest
            Wkb.Close False
        End If

        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
```